# Ajax returns empty string instead of a NULL value

Tags: javascript, ajax, null

I searched and it appears that I have the opposite problem to everyone else (They wonder why ajax returns null). I WANT my jquery/ajax function to return null if PHP echoes NULL but I get empty string instead. It's not a big deal but it's something that doesn't make sense for me now.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
        success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});     
</script>

<?php 

    echo NULL;

?>

//logs: empty string
```

I'll be embarased by the answer but I gotta know.

Thanks

Comment: `echo`ing `NULL` means that the headers get sent, there are two line breaks and then the end, right? Which means you're serving an empty string as the content..

Comment: [Fiddler 2](http://fiddler2.com/) is GREAT at sniffing network access and seeing exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echo NULL try returning an object that has a single property having value null

e.g.

```
obj
{
returnValue = NULL
}
```

I am not sure of PHP syntax but what i want to say is to wrap your return value in an object. and on client side you will get obj.returnValue as NULL instead of empty string

Comment: Thanks. That worked fine. I had to JSON serialize the object to echo it and then parse it in jQuery. That's the whole problem as I didn't know that you can only echo strings.